# matlab while loop not checking condition the first time it is broken

Tags: matlab, ode

Below is a simple matlab code to solve a first order ode using euler method.ODEFUN is the ode,TSPAN is the 2 element vector of initial and final time, Y0 is y(0) and h is the step size. It is coded such that if overshoot occurs, it will adjust h to fall at the ending time specified. However the outcome is little unexpected as the TOUT and YOUT vector have the ending value twice, instead of just once. It seems the while loop isnt checking the condition the first time it broke

```
 function [TOUT,YOUT] = euler2(ODEFUN,TSPAN,Y0,h)
 t=TSPAN(1);
 i=1;
 TOUT(1)=t; 
 YOUT(1)=Y0;
 tlim=TSPAN(2);
 while t  < tlim
   i=i+1;
   m=ODEFUN(t,Y0);
   if (t+h)>TSPAN(2)
       h=h-(t+h-TSPAN(2));
   end
   y=Y0+h*m;


   t1=t+h;
   TOUT(i)=t1;
   YOUT(i)=y;
   t=t1;
   Y0=y;
end
```

[image]

edit: code works as expected when inputs are changed
 [image]

Comment: try to put the increment of `i` at the end of the loop. And, don't use `i` as a variable, it's a keyword for the imaginary unit.

Comment: Any explanation for the problem?

Comment: mm.. not really. Did you try the increment of `i` in the end of the loop? It seems to me something with precision, because if the loop been evoked lastly, `h` should get the difference between `TSPAN(2)` and `t`, and then `t` should be updated to be `TSPAN(2)` and terminate the loop. It happens also when all the numbers are integers?

Comment: For your edit: tha fact that `a` get two identity values at the end, in the first code, can explain that `YOUT` also get it.

Comment: I suggest you step through your code with the debugger and monitor the value of `t` on each iteration.